# Split on multiple instances of word in string

Tags: php

I have strings like this:

```
$T = '[{"X":"13","Y":"76", "R":"90"},{"X":"12","Y":"24","R":"-19"}]}';

$A = '[{"X":"1","Y":"6", "R":"0"},{"X":"1","Y":"4","R":"9"},
    {"X":"12","Y":"24","R":"-19"}]}';
```

I want to find each X value in the string, and get the value after them.

Note that the number of X values differs.

For example, I want:

```
13, 12, 1, 1, 12
```

I tried `explode()`, but that only grabbed the first X value (13). I am new to PHP, and don't know an elegant solution. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Your strings are JSON. See [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^ Then see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php and possibly http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: @AlexHowansky I don't' think this is valid json.

Comment: Might have to `trim($T, '}');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last curly brace (`}`) of your strings to have valid `json`, i.e:

```
$A = '[{"X":"1","Y":"6", "R":"0"},{"X":"1","Y":"4","R":"9"},
    {"X":"12","Y":"24","R":"-19"}]}';
$A = trim($A, '}');
$json = json_decode($A, true);
foreach($json as $value)
{
    echo $value['X'];
}
# 1112
```